# Can DataGridViewCheckBoxCell accept CheckState.Indeterminate programatically, but not via clicking?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have the followowing `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell` which is part of my `DataGridView`:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell(true) {Value = CheckState.Unchecked};
grdRow.Cells.Add(cell);
grdRow.Tag = key;
grdFilter.Rows.Add(grdRow);
```

Later on, I update its state based on whether other check boxes are checked.

```
var numChecked = cells.Count(c => c.Value.Equals(true));
cbCell.Value = (numChecked == cells.Count) ? CheckState.Checked : (numChecked == 0 ? CheckState.Unchecked : CheckState.Indeterminate);
```

This works great.  However, if the user clicks the checkbox, it cycles between Checked, Unchecked, and Indeterminate.  I only want to cycle between *Checked* and *Unchecked*.

If I set `TriState` to `False` on the cell, it no longer allows me to set the `Value` to `CheckState.Indeterminate`.

Is there a way to get the behavior I want?

**Update:**

I've tried trapping the `CellValueChanged` event like so:

```
void DataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var changedCell = grdFilter.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if(changedCell.Value.Equals(CheckState.Indeterminate))
        changedCell.Value = CheckState.Unchecked;
}
```

However, this has no effect.  I can still click through all three states.  I've verified the event does fire under the debugger, and the `Value` property is indeed getting set to `CheckState.Unchecked`.

Comment: Register on the value changed event and when the new value is `CheckState.Indeterminate` set it to `CheckState.Unchecked`.

Comment: @JeffreyWieder - Yea, for some reason setting the cell `Value` within the `CellValueChanged` event handler doesn't seem to take effect.  There must be something I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CellValueChanged event I think is firing too late for you to catch the user changing the value for your CheckBox column.  Try wiring up the CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged event and commit the change:

```
void dgv_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    dgv.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

Then in your CellValueChanged event, you can just change the ThreeState property:

```
private void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  ((DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]).ThreeState = false;
}
```

You probably should filter your columns to only do this on your CheckBox columns, etc.

Comment: This doesn't work.  When I set `ThreeState` to `false`, it will no longer allow me to programatically set the checkbox to `Indeterminate`.  Perhaps my question wasn't clear.  I want to be able to set the checkbox to `Indeterminate` in code, but I *don't* want the user to be able to do it.

Comment: Perhaps I have to wire up some code to set `ThreeState` back to true when the linked check boxes become mixed again.  This seems *incredibly* hacky!

Comment: @MikeChristensen I interpreted that once the user starts clicking, the ThreeState went away.  If you have some button function to put it all back to indeterminate, then just add that to the code to set the ThreeState back to True.  I don't find that too hacky, it's just a way to get it done with your requirements.

Comment: Great, trying that now.  Basically I'm implementing a *Check All* header row.  If you check the header row, it checks all the child rows.  If you uncheck the header row, it unchecks all the child rows.  If you check or uncheck one of the child rows, it sets the header row to checked, unchecked, or indeterminate.  Yea, it's a lot of hoops to jump through just to show a mixed state on the header row, but I'm kinda OCD.

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.  Basically I just need to add logic to only have the cell in `ThreeState` mode exactly when it needs to be, and off at all other times.